# How to add line numbers to a text file from a batch file (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file

How would I be able to add line numbers to a text file from a batch file / command prompt?

e.g.

```
1 line1
2 line2
etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%G IN (1, 1, 100) DO (
     echo %%G line%%G
)
```

This will probably only work in a batch file and not on the command line.

For more info, [see this page](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

If you want to loop over an existing file and add numbers to it, you'd have to process the file with a [for /F loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) instead, and within each loop iteration use a statement like `set /a counter+=1` to increment your counter. Then spit out each line to a new file and finally replace the old file with the new one.

Comment: I might well be wrong, but I'm guessing he wants to add the numbers to an existing file.

Comment: Sorry, i meant for an external file

Comment: A FOR /F loop will ignore empty lines

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could get was this, which does not work:

```
@echo off

set file=%1     
set x=1

for /f "delims=|" %%i in (%file%) do (
  echo %x% %%i
  set /a x=%x%+1
)
```

The `set` inside the `for` loop does not work (because we're in crappy DOS).

Replacing the `set` with a `call` to another batch file to do the increment and setting of `x` does not work, either.

**Addendum**

Okay, adding the fixes suggested by @indiv, we get this (which does seem to work):

```
@echo off

set file=%1     
set x=1
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=|" %%i in (%file%) do (
  echo !x! %%i
  set /a x=!x!+1
)
```

Comment: See `help set` (near the end) for how to make `set` work inside a `for` loop.  You need to add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to your script and then for variables you want expanded at runtime instead of parse time you surround them with `!` instead of `%`.  Also, you're not in DOS.  You're in the Windows command shell.

Comment: `delims=|` destroy lines containing `|`, better use `delims=`, but it will also fails on lines containing `!`. And empty lines will not be processed. But the rest could work

Answer (score 1):

All way too complicated, let's necromance this. For Windows XP and later (we need findstr) the following is all it takes on the command line or in batch to add line numbers to an input file as the OP wanted...

```
type "in.txt"|findstr/n ^^ > "out.txt"
```

Comment: nice and clean... too bad that the line number can't be formatted as I wish